# Question about post-increment operator

Tags: java, post-increment

Why does the following code

```
int i = 1; 
System.out.print(i += i++);
System.out.print(i);
```

output 2 **two times** instead of 3 for the 2nd print?

Could somebody please shed some light on it?

Thanks.

Comment: It should be noted that in real world you should never code like this. Never.

Comment: @Grey: yes, just to figure this out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you realise that a++ works as follows (pseudocode):

```
func ++(ref a)
{
    int b=a;
    a=a+1;
    return b;
}
```

then it all makes sense.

Comment: `ref` is kinda nontrivial for Java programmers, you know ;)

Comment: hmm. For those who don't understand the ref part, I'm attempting to show that the value of the variable passed in (a) is changed at the call site by this function.

Answer (score 3):

It may seems like i should be 3 in the end.

However, if you look into the statement more closely

```
i += (i++)
```

is equal to

```
i = ( i + (i++) )
```

which is, in this case, 1+1.

The side effect of i++ is i=i+1=1+1=2 as you may have expected, however, the value of i is override after the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the Java bytecode syntax very well yet but according to me at bytecode level your code would look something like this :

```
int i = 1;  // iconst_1:    variables { }, stack {1}
            // istore_1:    variables {1}, stack { }
i += i++;   // iload_1:     variables {1}, stack {1}
            // iinc 1, 1:   variables {2}, stack {1}
            // iadd:        variables {2}, stack {2} ...Note that here 1 gets added to the value on stack
            // istore_1:    variables {2}, stack {2} ...Here the variable value will overwrite the stack value
```

I think this explains the output you are getting pretty well. :-)

Experts, please correct me if I am wrong...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is an issue with not knowing how the postfix unary operator (*expr*++) works. It is the order in which the statements are evaluated that is creating the confusion.

```
int i = 1;
System.out.println(i += i++); // Output: 2
```

So the last statement is the same as the following two statements in this order:

```
i++; // i is now 2 for the rest of this statement and the program
i = 1 + 1; // i is assigned again
```

So the postfix operator is evaluated first but then the whole line is evaluated but using the previous value of i.

So, to use another example that would make this more clear:

```
int i = 2;
System.out.println(i += i++); // Output: 4
System.out.println(i); // Output: 4
```

And another example:

```
int i = 2;
System.out.println(i = i + i++ + i--); // Output: 7
System.out.println(i); // Output: 7
```

The second line is assigning *i*. The first *i* is 2, the next *i* is also 2, but now the third *i* is 3 because *i++* has changed the value of *i*. As the case from before, *i--* will not have any affect on i because it will get rewritten with *i = 2 + 2 + 3*.

```
int i = 1;
System.out.println(i = i++ + i); // Output: 3
System.out.println(i); // Output: 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
1 + 1 == 2.
```

Therefore:

```
i + i == 2
```

and

```
i += i == 2
```

and then

```
i += i++ == 2
```

Pretty straight forward.

Comment: I'm afraid the post increment operator is not really explained here.